# How do I get Adaljs Import working in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, webpack-2, adal.js

How do I use adaljs in my AngularJS app when installed by npm? It works if I use a cdn reference but I cant use cdn's in production. If I install it using npm then it doesnt recognize AdalAngular.

```
import AdalAngular from 'adal-angular'
```

I am using Webpack to transpile the code. Could it be that ADAL doesn't support modules?

Comment: which library & version you are installing ?

Comment: The version of adaljs is 1.0.14

Comment: @BeesNees m facing same issue. AdalAngular is not working nor is AdalModule. do you remember the solution ? I can see that tests in node_module use AdalAngular

Answer (score 0):

Your statement seems Angular2 used . If you are using Angular1  , you could refer to document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular and refer to code sample here : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp

Comment: I am using Angular 1.5

Comment: Also my question was how to reference Adaljs from node_modules when installed from npm. In the example provided the script is included as part of the app scripts and directly referenced.